# obtener ultimo numero de registro de la base de datos mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

Estamos implementando un sistema de registro de mascotas, al momento de registrar los datos de la mascota se debe autogenerar un número de registro por cada mascota registrada, el campo nregistro es varchar en la base de datos, entonces nosotros queremos obtener el último nregistro convertirlo en entero, sumarle uno y luego insertarlo en la base de datos, estamos trabajando con php y mysql

Código php

```
// Seleccionando el ultimo numero de registro de la mascota
    $sqlSelectRegistro = "SELECT MAX(nregistro) FROM mascota";

    //Convirtiendo el registro de la mascota en entero
    $conIntRegisMascota = (int) $sqlSelectRegistro;

    //Sumando 1 al regitro de la mascota
    $registroMascota = $conIntRegisMascota + 1;
```

Comment: Y cuál es el impedimento para llegar al objetivo? No sería mejor agregarle un id auto-incremental? Para que no tengas que consultarlo, volverlo entero y sumarle `1`?

Comment: Si estan implementando el sistema todavia, como recomendacion cambien ya ese valor a un numerico y haganlo autoincrementable. Mas alla de eso, cual es el problema?

Comment: En vez de declarar nregistro como varchar lo declaras como auto-increment y obtendrías el mismo resultado. Es decir cada vez que insertes una fila a la base de datos el campo irá tomando valores sucesivos (1,2,3....) de forma automática.

Comment: Te explico el id existe y es auto-incremental, esto rige por que no solo se registraran perros, gatos, patos, entonces al momento de registra ejemplo un perro debe de generara P0001, gatos G001 el prefijo ya lo tenemos que nos falta es el campo registro de la mascota. espero me entiendas

Comment: Yo tendría una tabla de tipo con valores 1 | PERRO, 2 | GATO, cada uno con su ID y sería un references a mi registro de paciente. Pero soy yo normalizando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manejar de esa forma los registros de id a la larga podría hacerte algo complicado el desarrollo a largo plazo, si no tienes las validaciones correctas puede que esto incluso lo complique aun más pero lo que tienes que hacer es idear una mejor forma de registrar todos tus datos mediante un ID que no le tengas que estar sumando 1 en todo momento y que te permita identificar todos tus registros de manera sencilla. Una forma de hacerlo es la que te planteo a continuación.

**PHP**

```
$date = new DateTime();
$newId = $date->format('YmdHis');
```

En este caso lo que te planteo es crear un ID con el tiempo actual en el que estas, en este caso yo le agregue el año, mes, dia, hora, minuto y segundo actual pero tu puedes ponerle mas o menos dependiendo de tu caso o incluso agregarle algo mas a parte de la fecha, de esta forma evitas tenerle que estas sumando 1 a la fecha y tendrías un id de cierta manera mas limpio para que lo integres a tu base de datos.

Si quieres seguir implementando tu idea lo mejor seria usar un ID auto-incremental desde la propia BD de MySQL.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, se acepto..